# VB.NET DataSet Update

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Why my set of codes didn't update in DataSet? Then it goes to Error. Please anyone check this code and point me out where I am missing. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim conxMain As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DBTest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=pwds")

    Dim dadPurchaseInfo As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsPurchaseInfo As New DataSet1
    Try
        Dim dRow As DataRow

        conxMain.Open()

        Dim cmdSelectCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock", conxMain)
        cmdSelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 30

        dadPurchaseInfo.SelectCommand = cmdSelectCommand
        Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dadPurchaseInfo)

        dadPurchaseInfo.Fill(dsPurchaseInfo, "Stock")


        For Each dRow In dsPurchaseInfo.Tables("Stock").Rows
            If CInt(dRow.Item("StockID").ToString()) = 2 Then
                dRow.Item("StockCode") = "Re-Fashion[G]"
            End If

        Next
        dadPurchaseInfo.Update(dsPurchaseInfo, "Stock")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error : ")
    Finally
        If dadPurchaseInfo IsNot Nothing Then
            dadPurchaseInfo.Dispose()
        End If

        If dsPurchaseInfo IsNot Nothing Then
            dsPurchaseInfo.Dispose()
        End If

        If conxMain IsNot Nothing Then
            conxMain.Close()
            conxMain.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message thrown? And which line of the code is it thrown from?

Comment: Hi. o. k. w,

Here is exception message I got
--------------------
InvalidOpeartionException was caught


Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

------------

Comment: @RedsDevils: Does your "stock" table has a primary key column?

Comment: nope! I used StockID as primary key but I didn't define at Table Structre.

Comment: @RedsDevils: It's recommended you set that column as primary key, but that's beside the point. I'm just guessing the query constructor is not able to generate an update statement for a table which doesn't have an identifier.

Comment: I've already changed StockID to primary key and run program again, it doesn't update too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your condition in the loop get executed (set a break point!)? Where is the error thrown? *What* error?

Also, why does it use `ToString` at all? This seems redundant.

```
If CInt(dRow.Item("StockID")) = 2 Then
```

Should be enough.

Finally, you’re performing redundant cleanup:

```
If conxMain IsNot Nothing Then
    conxMain.Close()
    conxMain.Dispose()
End If
```

`Dispose` implies `Close` – no need to perform both operations:

> `Close` and `Dispose` are functionally equivalent.

[[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx)]

Comment: Thanks Konard Rudolph! I got it based on your error correction to my program! :) Thanks a lot. It takes me the whole day to solve! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Does your dataAdapter has update command ?

(it looks like it doesn't - so it doesn't know what do to with update....)

Here is an Update Command example:(for an employee table with 3 columns - as listed below:

```
UPDATE [Employee]
SET [name] = @name
  , [manager] = @manager
WHERE (([id] = @Original_id) AND 
      ((@IsNull_name = 1 AND [name] IS NULL) OR
                             ([name] = @Original_name)) AND
      ((@IsNull_manager = 1 AND [manager] IS NULL) OR
                               ([manager] = @Original_manager)));


SELECT id
     , name
     , manager
FROM Employee 
WHERE (id = @id)
```

You can see it is a general update that can handle changes in any field.

Comment: How about this part?

        For Each dRow In dsPurchaseInfo.Tables("Stock").Rows
            If CInt(dRow.Item("StockID").ToString()) = 2 Then
                dRow.Item("StockCode") = "Re-Fashion[G]"
            End If
        Next
  It says to update dataAdapter, isn't it?

Comment: You gave the adapter a select command (check your code) you need to give it an update command.
your code changes the data - but the adapter need to know what command to run to update it. 
you can use visual studio wizard to generate an update command, or write it yoursefl.

Comment: Dim cmdUpdateCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Stock SET StockCode='Re-Fashion(H)' WHERE StockID=2", conxMain)
            cmdUpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 30

dadPurchaseInfo.UpdateCommand = cmdUpdateCommand

Dim cbUpdate As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dadPurchaseInfo)

dadPurchaseInfo.Update(dsPurchaseInfo, "Stock")


-------------

I write like above and run but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show me the code snippet that call after I created Update Query in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I got it from the error correction of my program by Konard Rudolph!

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim conxMain As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DBTest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=pwds")

    Dim dadPurchaseInfo As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsPurchaseInfo As New DataSet1
       Try
            Dim dRow As DataRow

            conxMain.Open()

            dadPurchaseInfo.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock", conxMain)
            Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dadPurchaseInfo)


            dadPurchaseInfo.Fill(dsPurchaseInfo, "Stock")

            For Each dRow In dsPurchaseInfo.Tables("Stock").Rows
                If CInt(dRow.Item("StockID")) = 2 Then
                    dRow.Item("StockCode") = "Re-Fashion(H)"
                End If

            Next
            dadPurchaseInfo.Update(dsPurchaseInfo, "Stock")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error : " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Finally
            If dadPurchaseInfo IsNot Nothing Then
                dadPurchaseInfo.Dispose()
            End If

            If dsPurchaseInfo IsNot Nothing Then
                dsPurchaseInfo.Dispose()
            End If

            If conxMain IsNot Nothing Then
                conxMain.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
  End Sub
```

The above set of code work to update with DataSet! Thanks to stackoverflow community and who answered my question.

Here is ref:

- [How To Update a SQL Server Database by Using the SqlDataAdapter Object in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308055)
- [How to update a database from a DataSet object by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301248)

p.s: Like o.k.w said : The Table must have primary key. Thanks o.k.w!

Answer (score -1):

```
--MENU--
Dim login As New LoginClass
login.ShowDialog()

--CONEXION--
Private conec As SqlConnection
Dim stringCon As String = "Data Source= ;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password="
Public ReadOnly Property prConec() As Object
    Get
        Return conec
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub Conectar()
    Try
        conec = New SqlConnection(stringCon)
        If conec.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            conec.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

--BUSCAR--
funciones.Conectar()
Dim coman As New SqlCommand("sp_cliente", funciones.prConec)
Dim dt As New DataTable
coman.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
coman.Parameters.Add("@i_operacion", SqlDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "B"
dt.Load(coman.ExecuteReader())
grdClientes.DataSource = dt

--INSERTAR--
funciones.Conectar()
Dim coman As New SqlCommand("sp_articulo", funciones.prConec)
coman.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
coman.Parameters.Add("@i_operacion", SqlDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "I"
coman.ExecuteNonQuery()
Buscar()
Limpiar()

--COMBO--
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Codigo")
dt.Columns.Add("Descripcion")
Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr1.Item("Codigo") = "A"
dr1.Item("Descripcion") = "Activo"
dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
Dim dr2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
dr2.Item("Codigo") = "I"
dr2.Item("Descripcion") = "Inactivo"
dt.Rows.Add(dr2)
cmbEstado.DataSource = dt
cmbEstado.ValueMember = "Codigo"
cmbEstado.DisplayMember = "Descripcion"

--GRIDVIEW--
--1--
Dim grdFila As DataGridViewRow = grdClientes.CurrentRow
txtCedula.Text = grdFila.Cells(0).Value
--2--
If DataGridProductos.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim FLstArticulos As New FLstArticulos
    FLstArticulos.ShowDialog()
    DataGridProductos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = FLstArticulos.PrIdArticulo
End If

--GRIDVIEW.CELLENDEDIT--
If DataGridProductos.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
    Dim precio As New Double
    Dim cantidad As New Double
    precio = CDbl(grdRow.Cells(2).Value)
    cantidad = CDbl(grdRow.Cells(3).Value)
    DataGridProductos.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = PLTotalFilaItem(cantidad, precio)
    PLCargaTotales()
End If

Sub PLCargaTotales()
    Dim subTotal As Double
    Dim iva As Double
    For Each grd As DataGridViewRow In DataGridProductos.Rows
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(grd.Cells(4).Value) Then
            subTotal = subTotal + CDbl(grd.Cells(4).Value)
        End If
    Next grd
    txtSubtotal.Text = subTotal.ToString
    iva = Decimal.Round(subTotal`enter code here` * 0.12)
    txtIva.Text = iva.ToString
    txtTotalPagar.Text = (subTotal + iva).ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether those `--XYZ--` headers are supposed to be comments, `#region`s, or just regular post text, but as they are they won't compile, and you should fix that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.